# A Percentage of Averages

Tags: average, percentages

A company brags about the speed of their service, "75% of our assignments are completed in an average of 20 days."

Is this a meaningful claim? Or is it kind of like saying, "60% of the time, it works every time?"

How might this be calculated?

Thanks

Comment: Each assignment has a certain time until completion. Take the fastest $75\%$ of these processing times and the average is $20$ days.

Comment: I first understood it the other way around: 75% of the tasks are completed in less than average time, which is 20 days. This would also mean that 25% of the tasks take much more than 20 days. But now that I think of it, sonystarmaps's explanation makes more sense.

Comment: $95\%$ time a percentage is used in advertising, it is made up.  Yes, I made that up, but I suspect it is not far from the truth.  The fact that you can parse the sentence in a sensible way does not mean that it has any relationship with reality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion makes full sense, though there is some ambiguity in the meaning of "average.". Let $T$ be the waiting time, and let $a$ be the $75$-th percentile of $T$. Let $T^\ast=T|T\le a$.

It is not clear what is meant by average in this case, perhaps mean, perhaps median. So we are told that the mean (or median) of $T^\ast$ is $20$.

Comment: I don't know enough about this subject to understand what you mean with the * and | symbols. But I understand what sonystarmap is saying, and s/he said s/he's providing one possible example of what you wrote. So I'm going to mark yours as the answer.

Thanks

Comment: I was being perhaps unnecessarily technical, the $T^\ast$ is just a name, could have called it $X$. The technical part is $T|T\le a$. This is the waiting time **given** that the waiting time is $\le a$. @sonystarmap gave a good ntuitive description of what is meant by that. The intuitive description is I think adequate for informal purposes, and unaccepting my answer and accepting the other seems to me appropriate (unaccepting is not rejection).

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add an example of the calculation, assuming that average refears to the arithmetic mean, which does not have to be the case as stated in André Nicolas' answer.

Assume you are talking about 8 assignments overall and the processing time of each assignments in day is given by (randomly):

```
1 3 5 10 3 8 100 4
```

Now, if you are the company, you advertise your fastest $75\%$, so sorting the list we get

```
1 3 3 4 5 8 10 100
```

Now taking the first $75\%$ we are left with

```
1 3 3 4 5 8
```

where the arithmetic mean is
\begin{align}
\frac16(1+3+3+4+5+5)= \frac{24}{6}
\end{align} 
So the company could advertise, that $75\%$ of their assignments are completed within an average $4$ days.